# Number of members of a set in geometry

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a $2n \times 2n$ grid of unit squares divided into $2 \times 2$ contiguous squares. Suppose we wish to have a set of these unit squares such that

1. At least one unit square of each 2 x 2 square is in the set.
2. For any two squares in the set, there is a sequence of squares that start from the first square and lead to the second, and has any consecutive elements sharing a side.

What is the least number of squares in such a set?

I would need to find the optimal way of putting the squares in the set. I think it is some weird spiral, but I don't know the optimal.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think it's going to be some weird spiral. But other than that, I have no clue how to start the problem.

Comment: Do you have optimal sets for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ ?

Comment: After a little bit of search I would say : $\lceil\frac{3n^2}{2}\rceil-2$ for $n>1$